# Vertical Curve Formula

Tags: c#, .net, math

I'm making just a basic application that just writes pixels along a curve in C#.

I came across [this website with a formula that looks promising](http://www.sd-w.com/civil/vertical_curves.html). I believe this website is also talking about the same thing [here](http://street.umn.edu/Road/javahelp/HTML/Vertical_Curve_Calculation.htm).

What I don't really understand is how to implement it. I tried looking at the JavaScript code on [the first link](http://www.sd-w.com/civil/vertical_curves.html) but I can't really tell what data I need to supply. The things involving the PVC, PVI, or PVT are the things I don't understand.

The example situation I'm going to set up is just both of the grades (vertical incline/decline) is just 5 and -5. Let's say point 1 is at 0, 0 and point 2 is 100, 100.

Can someone explain some of the obscure variables in the formula and how would I use the formula to draw the curve?

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site. "I don't know how to implement it" is not a question. **Ask a question**.

Comment: Sorry for not explicitly stating my request and hopefully you can finally understand my request now that I am going to repeat what I said in the original post but with a question in front of it. "Can you help me understand the things I don't understand? These things are finding the PVC, PVI, and PVT." I'm pretty sure that one could assume that I want to figure out what I don't understand if I'm stating "I don't understand ..." What point is there to stating that I don't understand something if I'm not looking to understand it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. A good question for this site is something like "how do I data-bind a DataSet that contains query results to a GridView in a C# Windows Forms project?" A *specific*, *technical* question. No one here knows why you don't understand the things you don't understand, but plenty of people here know how to bind datasets to grid views.

Comment: "can you explain the things i don't understand how to calculate since i need to understand them because this is a formula and it could be implied by me stating that i don't understand them that i want to understand them because it's vital to actually making it work properly" i said it, that's it, that's what i'd really appreciate. can i stop being hassled over semantics now?

Comment: I'm not hassling you over semantics; I'm *helping* you by pointing out that the question you're asking is highly likely to be closed and then deleted as unanswerable. **Ask a better question.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, to draw a curve in 2D you vary one parameter, and then collect x,y point pairs, and plot the pairs.  In your case it will work to just vary the horizontal distance (x), and then collect the corresponding y-values, and then you can plot these.

As for the formula, it is very unclear.  Basically it's just a parabola with a bunch of (poorly defined) jargon around it.  To graph this, you want to vary x from 0 to L (this isn't obvious, btw, I had to work out the math, i.e., how to vary x so that the slopes would be as they suggest in the figure, anyway, it's 0 to L, and they should have said so).

I don't have C# running now, but hopefully you can translate this Python code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show
from numpy import arange

G1 = .1 # an initial slope (grade) of 10%  (note that one never uses percentages directly in calculations, it's always %/100)
G2 = -.02 # a final slope (grade) of 2%
c = 0    # elevation (value of curve when x=0, that is, y at PVC
L = 10.   # the length of the curve in whatever unit you want to use (ft, m, mi, etc), but this basically sets your unit system
N = 1000  # I'm going to calculate and plot 100 points to illustrate this curve

x = arange(0, L, float(L)/N)  # an array of N x values from 0 to (almost) L

# calculate the curve
a = (G2-G1)/(2*L)
b = G1
y = a*x*x + b*x + c  # this is shorthand for a loop y[0]=a*x[0]*x[0] + b*...

plot(x, y)    
show()

print (y[1]-y[0])/(x[1]-x[0]), (y[-1]-y[-2])/(x[-1]-x[-2])
```

The final line prints the initial and final slopes as a check (in Python neg indexing counts from the back of the array), and this match what I specified for G1 and G2.  The plot looks like:

[image]

As for your requests: "The example situation I'm going to set up is just both of the grades (vertical incline/decline) is just 5 and -5. Let's say point 1 is at 0, 0 and point 2 is 100, 100.", in a parabola you basically get three free parameters (corresponding to a, b, and c), and here, I think, you over-specified it.

What are PVC, PVT, and PVI?  PVC: the starting point, so Y_PVC is the height of the starting point. PVT: the ending point.  PVI: if you draw a line from PVC at the initial slope G1 (ie the tangent to the curve on the left), and similarly from PVT, the point where they intersect is called PVI (though why someone would ever care about this point is beyond me).